# Can I use addToBackStack() when I only imported android.app.FragmentManager? Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I'm trying to go back to my previous fragment

so I tried using `onBackPressed()` and here is my code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

I'm having an error in `super.onBackPressed()` and it says that "Cannot resolve method 'onBackPressed' so I'm wondering why so I've searched on how to go to my previous fragment and found out that I should used `addToBackStack()`

```
if (fragment != null) {
                android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager();
                android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container_expandable, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error in creating fragment");
            }
```

when I'm trying to put addToBackStack() is doesn't recognized it. Why is it like that? Is it because I'm using `android.app.FragmentManager`? or there are other solution for this?going back to the previous fragment? Thank you for the help

---

In my logcat it says
`Error:(88, 18) error: cannot find symbol method onBackPressed()`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it.

> getFragmentManager().popBackStack()

will not work if you do not addToBackStack

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.mainActivity_main_content, fragment).addToBackStack("Fragment");
            transaction.commit();
```

after you can catch click inside fragment

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_end, container, false);

        view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: in adding addToBackStack() i always see null value for it in different examples. is there a difference if i put my fragment and not using null instead?

Comment: I'm having an error saying `Error:(88, 18) error: cannot find symbol method onBackPressed()`

Comment: Did you try `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`  library instead of `android.Fragment`  ? @KairiSan

Comment: Do not use `super.onBackPressed()`  on your event.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this documentation for proper back navigation from fragments.

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html